# How to get continuous logs of Linux top command to store

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I am running a process process_a in loop .
I want to get top -H logs stored for all process_a running in loop.

```
top -b -H -p `pgrep -d, -f process_a`
```

the above command gave logs for process_a for first loop only

is there a way to get to get top logs for upcoming loops as well ?

Comment: Works for me if I pass `init` instead of `process_a`. Is the process still running at the second loop iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will repeat forever. I added the `-n 1` option. This allows you to rerun the `pgrep` for each iteration. Note: I used init for the name of the process. Change that to process_a for yours.

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ true ]; do
    top -b -H -n 1 -p `pgrep -d, -f init`
    sleep 1
done
```